# Закрытие jframe через некоторое время

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, пожалуйста, подскажите как сделать закрытие формы через некое время (минуту). На одной (1)jframe есть кнопка перехода на следующую *(2)jframe*,этой же кнопкой происходит запуск таймера, который отображается в *(2)jlabel-e*.

Необходимо чтобы после 1 минуты, (2)jframe закрылся и открылась другая форма. 

У меня получилось открыть форму, которую нужно, но закрыть *(2)jframe* не получается

```
public  ActionListener actionListener3 = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
          setVisible(false);
          for(int h=0;h<1;h++){
           System.out.println(jLabel20.getText());}
       if(tgl.jLabel20.getText().equals("00:10")){
           **текущая форма**.setVisible(false);
           таймер с (1)jframe - timer33.stop();
           таймер с (2)jframe- timer34.stop();**метод открытия нужной формы**();}}};
```

PS. два таймера из-за того, что для каждого наполнения формы разное время закрытия

Comment: Среда разработки тут ни к чему. Сношу метку и ее упоминание в тайтле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше использовать один JFrame но менять панель содержания внутри фрейма. Иначе вы будете работать с нативными окнами операционной системы со всеми вытекающими из этого последствиями.